# Why the image doesn't appear in ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have an image `(w=640px,h=1136)`. When I set it to `ImageView` with `full_parent` for the width and height. the image doesn't appear, why ?!

### edit

xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSplash"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="spalsh screen"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried following the configurations you described, and it seems to work for me. Posted below is my own XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainScreenActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" 
        android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

My initial though was that maybe you misspelled `fill_parent` and this is why it wasn't working. In any case you should use `match_parent` ([see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT)).

And I see that NickF has beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

From your posted code I see you have a mistake `full_parent` the correct value is `fill_parent` but this one is deprecated you should use `match_parent`.